# Cannot read property "email" of undefined - Nodejs Express

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to create an api server. I have created my user model and am trying to create a new user but each time I get property email (or any other request passed) not found. I don't understand where the problem is coming from. I am test running it on postman but I'm getting the same error and when I try making a post request from reactjs... Its the same thing. I will be happy if I could get an answer please. Thank you very much

this is my server.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

// Configuring the database
const dbConfig = require("./config/database.config.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

app.use(cors());

// Require Notes routes
require("./app/routes/user.routes.js")(app);

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
mongoose
  .connect(dbConfig.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// listen for requests
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 5000");
});

// define a simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: "Lolius Server is Running",
    time: new Date().toString(),
  });
});
```

This is the route

```
    // Create and Save a new user
exports.create = (req, res) => {
  User.find({ email: req.params.email })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user === []) {
        return res.status(500).send({
          message: "username already exists, please try again.",
        });
      }
      // Create a user
      const userModel = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        password: req.body.password,
        role: req.body.role,
        verified: { status: false, code: makeId(4) },
        location: {
          lat: req.body.lat,
          lng: req.body.lng,
        },
      });

      // Save user in the database
      userModel
        .save()
        .then((data) => {
          res.send({ data, message: "User registered successfully" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message:
              err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the user.",
          });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "An error occurred try again",
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: In your route you have both `req.params.email` **and** `req.body.email`. I'm guessing either `req.params` or `req.body` is undefined, should be one or the other. And given that it's a GET route, I think you use params rather than body

Comment: What's your `user.routes.js` looks like? Show the code

Comment: This is it
`module.exports = (app) => {
  const users = require("../controllers/user.controllers");

  // Create a new user
  app.post("/users", users.create);

  // Retrieve all users
  app.get("/users", users.findAll);

  // Retrieve a single user with userId
  app.get("/users/:userId", users.findOne);

  // Update a user with userId
  app.put("/users/:userId", users.update);

  // Delete a user with userId
  app.delete("/users/:userId", users.delete);
};
`